# My slidetoggle is not working while page converts to "https://"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is working fine till site is not "https://" but when site goes to "https://..." page slidetoggle stops working. What am I missing?
My code in header:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flipChat").click(function(){
    $(".cornerContactBox").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

My code in content:

```
<div class="livecontactCorner">
    <div class="flipChat">Contact us</div>
    <div class="cornerContactBox" style="display:none;">

            All content goes here..................

    </div><!--chatbox closing-->
</div><!--live chat corner closing-->
```

My css is :

```
.livecontactCorner{
    background:#CCC;
    width:300px;
    position:fixed;
    right:10px;
    bottom:0px;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:justify;
}

.livecontactCorner, .flipChat{
    border-top-left-radius:20px;
}

.cornerContactBox{
    height:auto;
    text-align:justify;
}

.flipChat{
    width:270;
    height:30px;
    background:#0066CC;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:arial,sans-serif; 
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:30px;
    color:#0077ff; 
    color:white; 
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

My working link (i.e. not in https://)
    [Working Link](http://digitalcinema.com.au/v/DigitalCinemaEmail/test.html)

**Not working link (i.e. in https://)** 
    [Not working Link](https://digitalcinema.com.au/v/DigitalCinemaEmail/test.html)

Any help is highly considered.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your jquery include needs to use https as well. The console in chrome says "[blocked] The page at https://digitalcinema.com.au/v/DigitalCinemaEmail/test.html ran insecure content from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js." Try changing your script tag that includes jquery to be https rather than http... Hm, looks like you might have some other issues with the code, but the reason the for the https not working is because of the jquery include script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always check your console for error. At the moment jQuery is being blocked because it uses http. So you should change from:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js

to

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js

and everything should be fine.

Comment: Ya it is working now. But it is causing my other menu problem. While I login as admin I get top bar (volusion bar) but after I put this code it is disabled. What should I do?

Comment: Hmm it's quite hard to say now, could you post the link to the page that's broken? Also check the console on Chrome dev tools or Firebug, I'm pretty sure you can see the error there.

Comment: Thanks for ur time Hieu Nguyen. I found the problem, i.e. Volusion uses jquery version 1.4.2 and I am using 1.10.1, that means I can't use this code.
Looking forward to that there is a way to achieve this function.